# Java CRON expression to disable job for date range

Tags: java, cron

We have a job scheduled for every day. Eg:  0 0 12 1/1 * ? *
We want to turn off the job for 15 days in january then run as scheduled(every day)

is there a way(cron expression) to do that automatically, So that I can avoid deployment to turn it on.

Comment: This is the second question I see today using `?` in the cron expression. What cron supports that?

Comment: Quartz: http://www.cronmaker.com/